# Linked server to Synapse Spark tables: Poor performance. Any best practices? (Aside from don't use linked servers)

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, azure-synapse, linked-server

**Old Linked Server Setup**:

- Linked server from SQL Server DB, to another SQL Server DB: Worked fine for its purposes.

**New Linked Server Setup:**

- Linked server from SQL Server DB, to 2 Synapse DBs:
- DB1 - A DB that's Views which point to CSV files in the Datalake: Performance is good. Possibly better than the 'old setup'
- DB2 - A DB that's External Tables, that point to Delta Files in the Datalake: Performance is bad, and it's easy to write a query that hangs.

Edit: I'm useing 4 part names.  For some simple queries, using openquery can return better results. But often it still hangs with openquery as well -   We also need to pass parameters so openquery isn't an overall solution.

So it's just queries across the linked server, when hitting those Spark, External-Tables-to-Delta, that works poorly.  e.g.

- Doing a join across the linked server, on two varchar columns = complete hang.  Changing datatypes in External Tables to nvarchar fixed this,[despite being against best practices per Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-serverless-sql-pool)

> Use the varchar type with some UTF8 collation if you're reading data from Parquet, Azure Cosmos DB, Delta Lake, or CSV with UTF-8 encoding.

- Doing simple WHERE clasues on varchar/nvarchar columns can cause performance to hang. e.g. WHERE left(varcharcolumn,1) = 'v', causes a query across the linked server, to go from 10 seconds to > 20 minutes, and presumably never would complete.

Linked Servers aren't the best, but I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing, that's making queries across the linked server to those Synapse Spark Tables so terrible.

Things I've tried:

- Switching from varchar to nvarchar when hitting a hang (which was a huge help, as stated above...for some reason)
- Being super specific on the length of varchar / nvarchar
- casting the varchar / nvarchar columns in my query
- Blindly changing Linked Server settings that shouldn't matter in this case

---

Example query

```
select
dp.visionwbs1

from LinkedServer.Db.dbo.dimproject dp

left join  LinkedServer.Db.dbo.dimclient dc
on dc.pk_clientid = dp.fk_clientid

--Runs in :04
```

But say this one:

```
select
dp.visionwbs1

from LinkedServer.Db.dbo.dimproject dp

left join  LinkedServer.Db.dbo.dimclient dc
on dc.pk_clientid = dp.fk_clientid

where left(dp.visionwbs1,1) = 'p'

-stalls after returning 141 rows, never to complete
```

The same queries if ran on a linked server, against a regular SQL server (the same tables are still available on our pre-Synapse database) - complete in :01 and < :01 respectively.

The above simple example, say - could run well if using OPENQUERY.  Often that doesn't help though, and is a moot point, as we need to pass parameters.

pastbin link of the live query statistics from the above one
https://pastebin.com/6ZtB65Tf

Comment: can you add some samples of your queries? are you using openquery or four-part names. as well as some queryplans

Comment: @siggemannen.  Four-part names.  I've tried openquery - sometimes helps, sometimes does not. Though many of our use cases involve passing parameters, so it's kind of a no-go.  Edited in a link to a pastebin of a live execution plan of a simple query that hangs (when using four-part - that one on openquery would work)